# PySide: base on the groupbox example of PySide-Example , issue An error native Qt signal is not callable

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qpushbutton

Base on  the groupbox example of  [PySide-Example](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/source/060dca8e4b82f301dfb33a7182767eaf8ad3d024%3aexamples/widgets/groupbox.py), I add a clicked slot to the `pushButton`, such as:

```
    def createPushButtonGroup(self):
                 ...
        pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("&Normal Button")
        pushButton.clicked(self.normalClick)
                 ...


    def normalClick(self):
        print self.sender.pushButton.text()
```

But it issues an error: `TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable`.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve this problem like this:

```
...
pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.normalClick(pushButton))
...

def normalClick(self, sender):
    print sender.text()
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: You can use the sender() method, so no need to call the normalClick method with the extra argument. def normalClick(self): print self.sender().text()